# How to get proper region ID from the dependency class path in Java?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I want to get groupIds of the dependencies that my app is using.
I have a filePath lists which locally looks like this:

```
/Users/myName/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar

/Users/myName/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar

/Users/myName/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar

/Users/myName/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.1/junit-4.13.1.jar
```

Looks like, we have a pattern, counting from the end by slashes we have the jar, version, artifact, and then there is the groupId. But the trick is that not always group id has the same amount of words, jakarta.annotation, and org.springframework have 2, sometimes there is 3, or just 1.

Furthermore not always the path looks the same, I believe on the server it's not in the .m2/repository catalog.

Does anybody know how to get group IDs from the dependencies in our app?

Comment: Hello, can you instead parse the pom file for your application? Or may be use the mvn dependency:tree and then parse the result?

Answer (score 0):

You leave out the last two directory names and the file name, then you get the groupId.

Example:

/Users/myName/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar

leads to `jakarta/annotation`, then replace `/` by `.` and you are finished.

Comment: What if there is just one? like /Users/myName/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.1/junit-4.13.1.jar

And how do I know how many are there?

Comment: Same rule. You leave out `junit/4.13.1/junit-4.13.1.jar`, so the resulting groupId is `junit`. So it does not matter if there is one, two, or maybe five. Just take everything after `.../repository/` and leave out the last two directories and the file name.

Comment: I believe there is not always ```.../repository/```, that's the point. I wrote it in the question description. Locally fine, but what on the server?
I need versatility solution.

Comment: Ok, I did not read the question carefully enough. If you have no way to figure out the base directory, then the method is not really applicable. Then it might be better to use the `dependency:tree` or to add the list of dependencies during build to some file, like in METAINF.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use dependency:tree in plain java? If not how can I implement such solution as a function in java, spring?